# ¿Cómo implementar un bootstrap personalizado?

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un bootstrap personalizado y me gustaría implementarlo en mi proyecto de ruby on rails, ¿Cómo puedo implementarlo?
https://github.com/IFARHU/taboga

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas tener instalado [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) en tu equipo, luego ejecuta los comandos detallados en [la instalación del proyecto](https://github.com/IFARHU/taboga#instalaci%C3%B3n). Al terminar, tanto las dependencias creadas en la carpeta `bower_components/` como los assets personalizados para bootstrap de `build/` deberías copiarlos a tu proyecto rails.

Comment: es buena tu respuesta, pero ese toma los otros archivos sparkline etc? hay uno compilado y otro precompilado? Cuál sería mejor el preocompilado o compilado?

Comment: Revisando los releases que te recomendé, en realidad no sirven de mucho, porque esos vienen del proyecto de bootstrap original desde donde se realizó el fork. Revisa mi modificación de la respuesta.

Comment: pero donde instalo todo en el application.css.scss?

Comment: Ahí solo tienes que poner los `require` a los css de bootstrap, taboga, etc. Lo mismo en `application.js`

Comment: Y como te decía antes, debes guardar los css y js donde corresponda en la carpeta `app/assets` o `vendor/assets`. Tu ahí decides como los organizas.